# Emacs tramp, version control and toggle-read-only

Tags: emacs, tramp

When using emacs 24 **w/tramp** on remotely RCS-controlled files, the toggle-read-only function (^X^Q) does not issue the usual "This file is under version control, blah, blah".

Instead it flips the read-only permissions without checking out the file. This is catastrophic, as the next checkout will overwrite changes etc.

How do I get the standard behavour?

I tried

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-q" 'vc-toggle-read-only)
```

which does not really address the issue.

To clarify: I want to have the version control warning when editing remote files - I currently get nothing.

Cheers, alf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled a copy of vc-toogle-readonly, from Emacs 23, renamed it to avoid clashes, dropped it into site-lisp, byte compiled it, and loaded it from .emacs:
(load-library "old-toggle-readonly")
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-q" 'old-toggle-read-only)

Works a charm.